# How to get user avatar picture on Java telegram bot?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I use Java and [telegrambots](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots) library. Please show an example of how to get the user's avatar.

```
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {

            String massageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            User user = update.getMessage().getFrom();
            languageCode = user.getLanguageCode();
            if (massageText.equals("/start")) {
                System.out.println("UserAvatarPicture --> " + Avatar????);

            } else {
                sendMessage(chatId, localization.getLocalizedString(languageCode, "commandWasNotRecognized"));
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    GetUserProfilePhotos getUserProfilePhotos = new GetUserProfilePhotos();
    getUserProfilePhotos.setUserId(update.getMessage().getChatId());

    try {
        UserProfilePhotos result= execute(getUserProfilePhotos);
        
        //show result             
        System.out.println(result.getPhotos());

    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```